# opera extension and Microsoft edge extension compatibility

Tags: opera, microsoft-edge-extension, opera-extension

I have a chrome extension I want to test to see if it's compatible with opera and Microsoft edge, please how can I test its compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like first, you need to port your Chrome extension before testing it with the Edge browser.

Microsoft Edge allows you to port your Chrome extension with minimal changes. The Extension APIs and manifest keys supported by Chrome are code-compatible with Microsoft Edge. For a list of APIs supported by Microsoft Edge, navigate to [API support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/api-support).

To port your Chrome extension, complete the following steps.

1. Review the Chrome extension APIs used in your extensions with the Microsoft Edge extensions [supported APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/api-support) list.
2. If the name **Chrome** is being used in either the name or the description of the extension, rebrand the extension for **Microsoft Edge**. This step is required to pass the certification process.
3. Test your extension to check if it works in Microsoft Edge by [sideloading your extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/getting-started/extension-sideloading).
4. If you face any issues, you may debug your extensions in Microsoft Edge by using the DevTools.
5. Follow the [publishing guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/publish-extension) to publish your extension on the Microsoft Edge Add-ons store.

Reference:

1. [Port your extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/port-chrome-extension)

Further, I suggest you contact **Opera browser support** to get information about how to test your Chrome extension with Opera.

Thanks for your understanding.